# IOS 7.1: UIButton's selected title not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, selected, ios7.1

Today I upgraded my iPhone OS to **iOS 7.1**.

Everything looks good in the new iOS, but I have a critical issue regarding `UIButtons` in the app I'm working on.

The selected state was gone in every button. For instance, **Like** button has title of **"Liked"** when selected but it's not shown at all when selected right now.
Buttons have only text without background/image in every state.
I tried to build and test the app in **Xcode 5.1**, but still can't see the selected states in buttons.

Does anyone else have this issue or could help me solve it?

Comment: it was working extremely fine in iOS 7.

Comment: I have the same issue: I have set two different attributed titles (selected and normal) using -[UIButton setAttributedTitle:... forState:UIControlStateSelected] but when I set the button to .selected = YES, nothing is shown at all.

It worked fine under iOS 7.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm facing here.

Comment: there is no issue experienced in iOS7.1 like you have described, the `selected` state is working propery with _System_ or _Custom_ buttons with _attributed title_ as well. I've tested it on simulator and real device, so, please, provide more information, because that is insufficient to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fixed it!**
Finally I was able to fix it and it was because of improvement of `UIButton` behaviour in **iOS 7.1**.

They just started rendering round-rected shape filled with tint color when `UIButton` is selected.
[image][image]

It was semi-transparent one in **iOS 7** and I remember that I put clear color just to make the buttons clear to see.
That was the issue and they rendered transparent rectangle around the buttons and we're unable to see anything when selected at all!
Hope this would help others who have the similar issues.

Comment: so i'm having a similar issue. i have a UIButton with images, but since 7.1. it's drawing a blue border around the text, which i don't like and want to take out. In other words when the button is selected=YES, it looks like your first image. how do i make it look like your second image??

Comment: I know this one is old, but I am too struggling to get rid of this iOS 7.1 behaviour i.e. get rid of this blue round rectangle around the title when the button is selected. Haven't succeeded yet. Any clue?